# installing programs without having internet

Tags: installation, 10.04, usb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I install software or packages without internet (offline)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline)

I have a friend that has a ubuntu machine (10.04) and has no internet.
they want some programs that dont require the internet to function. 
music production programs. but idk how to download a program from the Software Center or a PPA to put on usb.

any help?

I want something simple. i dont want to have to know all the packages the software center usually downloads with each program install.

Answer (score 0):

[Package database](http://packages.ubuntu.com/), this has what .debs you need.  Just download them and install them on your friends computer.

Comment: so if i download a program package, it with come with all it dependencies?

Comment: No.  but you can download those too via that site.